# Triangle - Trapezoid [Geometry]

Tags: geometry, triangles

I'm having trouble with following assignment:

"Sides of triangle are $13$, $14$, and $15$. Line parallel to the longest side cuts through the triangle and forms a trapezoid which has perimeter of $39$. Calculate the area of trapezoid."

It should look something like this
[image]

and the solution for area is $78.75$. However whenever I tried solving it I end up using formulas that lead to an over complicated calculation.

Answer (score 1):

By Heron’s formula, $[\triangle ABC] = … = 84$.

Let ABC be the triangle with $AB = 13, AC = 14$ and $BC = 15$. We also let the parallel line cut AB and AC at D and E respectively.

[image]

Since the two triangles are similar, we can let $\triangle ADE$ be $k$ times smaller than $\triangle ABC$.

Then, $AD = 13k$ & $DB = 13 – 13k$; $AE = 14k$ & $EC = 14 – 14k)$; $DE = 15k$ & $BC = 15$.

$∴ 39 = 15k + (13 – 13k) + 15 + (14 – 14k)$. This means $k = \dfrac {1}{4}$.

Because the two objects are similar, we have $\dfrac {[\triangle ADE]}{[\triangle ABC]} = \left(\dfrac {\left(\frac 14\right)}{1}\right)^2$.

∴ $\triangle ADE = 84 \times \dfrac {1}{16} = 5.25$

Result follows after subtraction.

Comment: +1 Precisely what I was going to say, but had no time to post. :-)

Comment: @CiaPan Others (with different approaches) beated me in time too. Also, thanks for the editing work.

Answer (score 0):

The triangle's vertices are:
$O(0\mid 0);\;A(15\mid 0);\;B(8.4\mid 11.2)$

The equations of $OB\quad$ and $AB\quad$ are, respectively,
$4x=3y\quad$ and $56x+33y=840\quad$

The intersections of the line $y=H\quad$ with
$OB\quad$ and $AB\quad$ are, respectively,
$M\left(\frac{3H}4\mid H\right)\quad$ and $N\left(\frac{840-33H}{56}\mid H\right)$

Calculate $\overline{OM}+\overline{MN}+\overline{NA}+\overline{AO}\quad$.
This is the perimeter. Set it equal to $39\quad$ and solve for $H$

Substituting this value of $H\quad$ into the expressions used in $M\quad$ and $N\quad$, subtract $\Delta MNB\quad$ from $\Delta OAB\quad$ and there you have it.

$\Delta OAB=\frac12\begin{vmatrix}
0&0&1\\15&0&1\\8.4&11.2&1
\end{vmatrix}\quad
\Delta MNB=\frac12\begin{vmatrix}
6.3&8.4&1\\10.05&8.4&1\\8.4&11.2&1
\end{vmatrix}$

*This just in:*
I performed the calculation as I described it above, and the result is indeed 78.75.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the points are
$A, B, $ and $C$,
and the lengths are
$|BC|=a, |AC|=b, $ and $|AB|=c$,
and a line $L$ parallel to
$AB$
makes a trapezoid of
perimeter $p$.

Let $U$ and $V$
be the points on,
respectively,
$AC$ and $BC$
where
$L$ intersects
$AC$ and $BC$.

If the distance from
$L$ to $AB$ is $d$,
and the distance from
$C$ to $AB$ is $h$,
then, 
by similar triangles,
$\dfrac{|UA|}{b}
=\dfrac{|VB|}{a}
=\dfrac{c-|UV|}{c}
=\dfrac{d}{h}
=r
$.

Since
$r
=\dfrac{c-|UV|}{c}
=1-\dfrac{|UV|}{c}
$,
$|UV|
=c(1-r)
$
so that
the perimeter is therefore
$c+|UA|+|VB|+|UV|
=c+r(a+b)+c(1-r)
=2c+r(a+b-c)
$.
Note that his agrees
with the extreme cases
$r=0$
(when $p = 2c$)
 and $r=1$
(when $p = a+b+c$).

Therefore,
if this is $p$,
then
$p
=2c+r(a+b-c)
=2c+rt
$,
where $t=a+b-c
$,
so that
$r
=\dfrac{p-2c}{t}
$
or
$d
=\dfrac{h(p-2c)}{t}
$.

The area of the trapezoid
is

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{d(c+|UV|)}{2}
&=\dfrac{h(p-2c)(c+c(1-r))}{2t}\\
&=\dfrac{h(p-2c)c(2-r)}{2t}\\
&=\dfrac{h(p-c)c(1+\dfrac{p-2c)}{t})}{2t}\\
&=\dfrac{h(p-c)c(t+p-2c)}{2t^2}\\
\end{array}
$

$h$ can be calculated
from Heron's formula
for the area of the triangle
$A
=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}
$
and
$A = \frac12 h\,c
$
or
$h
=\dfrac{2A}{c}
$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the horizontal cuts the triangle at an ordinate which is the fraction $t$ of the height.

The perimeter of the trapezoid is $13t+(1-t)15+14t+15=39$, so that $t=\frac34$ and the area of the trapezoid is $1-(1-\frac34)^2=\frac{15}{16}$ of the area of the triangle, hence

$$A=\frac{15}{16}\sqrt{21\cdot(21-13)\cdot(21-14)\cdot(21-15)}=\frac{15\cdot84}{16}=\frac{315}4.$$